# How to get an int out of selectedRowIndexs in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsindexset

I haven't worked in `Xcode`, `Objective C` or `Cocoa` before, and I decided to give `Swift` a try.
The simple app I'm building (for Mac OS, not iOS) displays in a table view some data stored in an array.

I'm trying to let the user delete a selected row, the only problem is I can't get an `index` in the form of a simple int from `myTableView.selectedRowIndexes`, this piece of code returns me an `NSIndexSet` object, and I don't know how to deal with it.

Since I want the user to be able to select only one row at a time I think `firstIndex` is what I need to use, [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIndexSet/isEqualToIndexSet:) says: `var firstIndex: Int { get }` but I really lack the knowledge to understand how to use it.

I'm sorry for the very basic question.
Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Just ask for the first index:

```
let allSelectedRows = myTableView.selectedRowIndexes
let selectedRow = allSelectedRows.firstIndex
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was that easy!!